# how can an ionic cordova app get shared url or file location from other apps on the same device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got a question about my ionic cordova app recently.
I'm trying to get a shared file location or an online file url from other apps on the device and upload the file to my backend storage. The uploading function is working well and I can upload videos and photos. But I have difficulty to get the file from other app, how can I do that? Which plugin should I use to do that? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

in Android native world that would translate to Intents. But iOS does not have such a concept. 
the plugin for that would be web-intent

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent/

As you may expect, the plugin won't work in iOS. It is also in Beta stage and you may face issues getting it to work